# Code to determine no of different items in two arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylist which is defined as follows .

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new arrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new arrayList<String>();

list1.add("sultan");
list1.add("Masum");
list1.add("sultan");
list1.add("Sorry");
list1.add("sultan");
list1.add("Masum");
list1.add("sultan");
list1.add("Tarek");
list1.add("sultan");

list2.add("Billal");
list2.add("Masum");
list2.add("Sorry");
list2.add("Sorry");
list2.add("sultan");
list2.add("Masum");
list2.add("Tanha");
list2.add("Tarek");
list2.add("Die");
```

I want to know the no of different items of the above two arraylist . For this I ahve the following piece of code .

```
int count=0;
for(String s1:list1)
{
    if(!list2.contains(s1)) 
        ++count;
}

for(String s2:list2)
{
    if(!list1.contains(s2)) 
        ++count;
}
```

But my code is very in-efficient . Can you please suggest me a better way to achieve my purpose ?

Comment: Look into the `Set` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `List` you should use `Set`. Then what you're looking for is [Symmetric Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference). If allowed, you can use Guava's [`Sets.symmetricDifference(Set, Set)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29)

Comment: I think a Set would not work here, since he has duplicate entries in each list.

Comment: +1 you are right,sorryI didn't understand the question correctly

Answer (score 3):

You could use [CollectionUtils.disjunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) (from Apache Commons Lib), and then do a `size()` on the returning Collection.

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add("sultan");
    list1.add("Masum");
    list1.add("sultan");
    list1.add("Sorry");
    list1.add("sultan");
    list1.add("Masum");
    list1.add("sultan");
    list1.add("Tarek");
    list1.add("sultan");

    list2.add("Billal");
    list2.add("Masum");
    list2.add("Sorry");
    list2.add("Sorry");
    list2.add("sultan");
    list2.add("Masum");
    list2.add("Tanha");
    list2.add("Tarek");
    list2.add("Die");

    int numOfDiffs = CollectionUtils.disjunction(list1, list2).size();
    System.out.println("Diffs: " + numOfDiffs);
```

Comment: What is the package name of CollectionUtils ?

Comment: That's from Apache Commons library.

Comment: exactly, I added explicitly in the post now!

Comment: There is also "standard" one in `Collections` class:

    `public static boolean disjoint(Collection<?> c1, Collection<?> c2)`

Comment: The "standard" disjoint returns a boolean indicating: if 2 collections have no elements in common. But OP wants to count the differences.

Answer (score 1):

At first you can init your lists as following:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"sultan", "Masum", "others..."}));
```

And then you can calculate how much common elements they have, and remove this number from total:

```
int list1 oldSize = list1.size();
list1.retainAll(list2); // In list1 you get common elements
```

and

```
count = oldSize - list1.size();
```

If you don't want to change your arrays, you can copy them as following:

```
Collections.copy(newArray, oldArray);
```