# Check one List<Integer> contains number of elements from another List<Integer> and put this into a Map

Tags: java, arraylist

I have multiple `List<Integer>`. I need to see if a list has numbers from another list.

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,4,3,9);
List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(3,1,8,7);
```

`list1` is the master list. I need to see how many elements from `list1` are in `list2` and `list3`. For each of these make that the key for the Map.

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> = [3,list2],[2,list3]
```

Comment: Well that's an entirely new question..... @tucker19 Please post your full question up-front. You have just edited your post into something completely different than the first revision.

Comment: @Tunaki I apologize for not being more specific. I fixed it now.

Comment: Why not just reopen ? Question is now concise and OP did efforts to fix it ..

Comment: Note that your new question makes no sense either. Why are there 3 lists but you mention 2? What do you want? What have you tried? Where is the map coming from? What should it contain exactly? I strongly suggest you to read [ask].

Comment: I would like to reopen but I can't make sense of the question and the result. Why is it `[3,list2],[2,list3]`? This is unclear, at best, the linked question will help you the most.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard working on a lottery program. I have the exact numbers matching with permutations but also want to add in if a entry may not have all numbers but some of them.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard no, there is only 3 elements from list1 in list2.

Comment: Ahhh I get it now, so you want to compare only list1 with all the other lists @Tunaki.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard yes, list1 is the master and I am checking how many elements from list1 are in lists2 and list3

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856355/counting-the-number-of-common-elements-between-two-arraylists-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631862/code-to-determine-no-of-different-items-in-two-arraylist or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379510/finding-duplicate-values-between-two-arrays

Comment: @tucker19 Simply wrap your list to compare then stream on them. Example : `Arrays.asList(list2, list3)` then `Map<Long, List<Integer>> result = lists.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.stream().filter(list1::contains).count(), Function.identity()));`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard thank you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard actually would it be possible to get a example more in Java 7 formatting? I am going to be dealing with a lot more than just 2 lists I am checking.

Comment: @tucker19 Yes, simply loop on your lists of list, then for each count those in commons using List#contains and put manually in the map.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard thats what I was thinking but I wanted to make sure that was a best solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Ah no actually, use Collections.frequency if there is possibility of multiple occurence @tucker19

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard yes there may be multiple lists with the same amount. So the Map could actually be Map=[3,[list2,listN],[2,[list3, listN+1]

Comment: @tucker19 I don't really have the time to help you anymore at the moment.. But that is in fact a completely different question than it was at the beginning. I encourage you to repost a new question with all the details you gave here in comments. + Make sure to read links posted by Tunaki.

Comment: If you keep checking against `list1` using `contains()`, you can improve performance by first converting it to a `Set`. The larger `list1` (now `set1`) is, the larger the performance gain. Alternative is so sort it and do a binary search.